# Different Prettier rules for different file types?

Tags: configuration, prettier

Does [Prettier](https://prettier.io/) have a way to specify different rules for different file types?

For example, I want a greater maximum [line length](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#print-width) in our template files (`.tsx`) because it's more common for markup to be more deeply nested than application code. But for all other files I would like to enforce the standard 80 char width.

Answer (score 18):

You can add [overrides](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html#configuration-overrides) like this:

```json
{
    "printWidth": 80,
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": "**/*.tsx",
            "options": {
                "printWidth": 120
            }
        }        
    ]
}
```

In that, `printWidth` option will be set to `80` for everything except files matching `**/*.tsx`, for which the `printWidth` will be `120`.